# The type initializer for System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting error trying to hit a MVC controller that constructs an EF derived context using EF 6.0.0 in an ASP.NET MVC5 project.

> The type initializer for System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion threw an exception.
>
> the type initializer for 'system.data.entity.internal.appconfig'
>   threw an exception configuration system failed to initialize entity
>   framework the type initializer for threw an exception could not load
>   file or assembly unrecognized element 'providers'. entity framework

Removing EF from all the shared projects as well as this project does not make a difference. The current context used to be used on an MVC4 site and then used when migrated to MVC5, but this new project was added as a new MVC5 project and the context is used in other MVC5 (migrated from MVC4 classes.) We're doing code based config using DbConfiguration...

Our config entry is defined:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

But I think that entry is not even required anymore with EF 6. I could be wrong, I am just gonna leave it in there for now. I know connection to the DB is working because that was the first thing I fixed (couldn't find DefaultConnection) when setting up init of the SimpleMembership database.

I also confirmed configuration is arranged correctly according to the other projects which jives with MS topics thrown in the internal exceptions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Well... I see what I missed... In the global.asax there was a few lines to init the DB in the other projects... and well... it was missing:

```
using (var context = new Data.FooContext()) 
{
    context.Database.Initialize(false);
}
```

I guess my followup question is why is this required here. This is a smell no?
 Maybe its not. But init was it... for me.